# OAuth2 JWT Authorization - Issue With Spring Security XML Configuration #oauth2.hasScope

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I need to use XML Configuration for some parts of my Spring Security Implementation. All that I am concerned with at the moment is JWT Authorization, the JWT is passed to me. Using Spring Security I determine if the user is authorized access to a REST API endpoint. I can't use Java configuration or the @PreAuthorize annotation.

As an FYI when I was originally using @PreAuthorize or an approach like:
.antMatchers("/students/**").access("#oauth2.hasScope('Scope:Admin')");

Everything worked fine. When I was forced to move to XML config and use the security:intercept-url approach, this issue came about.

The error I am getting is:

> "message": "Failed to evaluate expression
>   '#oauth2.hasScope('Scope:Admin')'"

The exception is:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to evaluate expression
>   '#oauth2.hasScope('Scope:Admin')'
>   at  org.springframework.security.access.expression.ExpressionUtils.evaluateAsBoolean(ExpressionUtils.java:30) ~[spring-security-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
>   ... removing exception spew for brevity ...
>   Caused by:
>   org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1011E:
>   Method call: Attempted to call method hasScope(java.lang.String) on
>   null context object

XML Config:

```
<!-- only enable this when deving -->
<!-- <security:debug /> -->  


<bean id="securityConfig"
    class="com.wmay.config.SecurityConfig">
</bean>

<bean id="resourceServerConfig"
    class="com.wmay.config.ResourceServerConfig">
</bean> 


 <bean id="methodSecurityConfig"
    class="com.wmay.config.MethodSecurityConfig">
</bean>

<security:http pattern="/**" use-expressions="true" auto-config="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/students/**"
            access="#oauth2.hasScope('Scope:Admin')"/>
</security:http>
```

Code Snippets:

```
@Override 
public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {     log.info("Configuring HttpSecurity");       
    httpSecurity.csrf().disable();  httpSecurity.cors().configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource());     
    //@// @formatter:off    
    httpSecurity
                .requestMatchers()
                .and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll();    
    // @formatter:on 
    }

@Override
protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
    log.info(
            "Enabling OAuth2 Method Expression Handler.");
    return new OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I needed to add some more entries into the XML configuration file.

```
<bean id="oauth2AuthenticationEntryPoint" 
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint" />
<oauth2:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter" 
        resource-id="${security.jwt.resource-ids}" token-services-ref="tokenServices"/>
<oauth2:web-expression-handler id="oauth2WebExpressionHandler" />


<security:http 
        pattern="/**"       
        entry-point-ref="oauth2AuthenticationEntryPoint"        
        authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager"
        use-expressions="true"
        create-session="stateless">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/students/**"
            access="#oauth2.hasScope('Scope:Admin')" />     
        <security:custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <security:expression-handler ref="oauth2WebExpressionHandler" />
    </security:http>
```